# Getting a sound trigger to work

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine, triggers, unityscript

I don't understand why my sound trigger is not working. I have created a GameObject and added an Audio Source to it (on Audio Source I have the `Play On Wake` and `Loop` checked. Then I added a Sphere Collider (I have the `Is Trigger` checked). Finally I added my script and added the sound clips into the inspector. Unity also says that: `"There are 2 audio listeners in the scene."` I have pretty much unchecked all the audio listeners and it still says it, what am I doing wrong?

Here is a look at my code:

```
 #pragma strict

 var WalkAudio:AudioClip; 
 var OutCry:AudioClip; 

 function Update (){

     var Audio= gameObject.GetComponent(AudioSource);

     if(Input.GetButton("Horizontal") || Input.GetButton("Vertical"))
     {

         Audio.Play();
     }
     else
     {

         Audio.Pause();
     }
 }

 function OnControllerColliderHit (hit : ControllerColliderHit)
 {
     var Audio= gameObject.GetComponent(AudioSource);

     if (hit.gameObject.tag == "templeFloor")
     {
         var groundType = 1;
         print("Temple");
         Audio.clip=OutCry;
     }

     else{
         Audio.clip=WalkAudio;
     }

 }
```

Comment: 1.There might be an Audio Listener attached to Main Camera.
2.Check if your Audio Clip is a 3D Sound. if it is, it may not be hearable if your object is away from your camera. So make it 2D Audio Clip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said:

> I have pretty much unchecked all the audio listeners

The component `AudioListener` attached to the `Main Camera` **must be enabled**. Probably you have used `LoadLevelAdditive` so you have two camera and two `AudioListener` components, one on each of them. Please make sure this additive camera and any other gameObject should have this component disabled.

Also *at runtime*, you can search which component(s) have `AudioListener` component attached using this in the `Hierarchy` window search bar.

```
t:AudioListener
```

This should help you out. Also double check using `Debug.Log` that `OnControllerColliderHit` function calls and `Audio.clip` is not null after assignment. Also is it necessary to play sound in `Update` ?

Also, you should move this line from `Update` to `Start` function instead, due to performance cost:

```
var Audio= gameObject.GetComponent(AudioSource);
```

and use this `Audio` variable throughout your script.